# AutoFixture and XUnit2 - Combining TheoryData and AutoData

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, xunit, autofixture

In the tests I'm currently writing I need to mix test-specific data with random entries that ideally I would like AutoFixture to generate.
I'm using TheoryData to create test-specific data set:

```
internal sealed class TestSpecificData : TheoryData<int, string>
{
    // Addition of test cases input.
}
```

In my XUnit2 test case I would like to do the following:

```
[Theory]
[AutoData]
[ClassData(TestSpecificData)]
public void MyTestCase(int first, string second, double third)
{
    // Test scenario.
}
```

In the above test case I would like AutoFixture to generate only the last parameter: "double third" and use data available in TestSpecificData theory data for the first two parameters.
Attempting to run above code results in InvalidOperationException with following message:

```
"The test method expected 3 parameter values, but 2 parameter values were provided."
```

I know I could use an InlineAutoData attribute, but there are a lot of test-specific entries and it would not be an ideal solution, since I would have to declare a separate InlineAutoData for each case. Moreover I would like to reuse test entries in different test cases, so this is why I'm attempting to use TheoryData.
I also tried to create a custom AutoFixture attribute that inherits from AutoDataAttribute, but I can't seem to make it work like I would like it to.
I would appreciate any suggestions or different solutions that would help me achieve desired outcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no support for `ClassDataAttribute` in `AutoFixture.XUnit2`. However there is currently a [pull request](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/pull/1257) opened that adds this exact feature to `AutoFixture.NUnit3`. You could draw some inspiration from there.

If you manage to come up with an implementation please consider filing a pull request on the official [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) repository.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. A bit of a shame, but it seems I'll have to find a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

When looking for this, I found
[a workaround for MemberAutoDataAttribute](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/1142#issuecomment-545579385). With a slight modification (replacing `MemberDataAttribute` with `ClassDataAttribute`) we got it to work.

To create an attribute with customizations I then derive from `ClassDataAttribute`, for example:

```
public class MyTypeClassAutoMoqDataAttribute : ClassAutoDataAttribute
{
    public MyTypeClassAutoMoqDataAttribute(Type @class)
        : base(@class,
            () => new Fixture()
                .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization())
                .Customize(new MyTypeCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The classAttribute configuration below, which combines theorydata with autodata, can be used.

```
public class ClassAutoMoqDataAttribute : CompositeDataAttribute
{
    public ClassAutoMoqDataAttribute(Type className)
        : base(new ClassDataAttribute(className), new AutoMoqDataAttribute())
    {
    }
    
    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        if (testMethod == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testMethod));
        }
        var theoryAttribute = Attributes.FirstOrDefault();
        var data = theoryAttribute.GetData(testMethod);

        var autoDataAttribute = Attributes.ElementAt(1);
        if (autoDataAttribute == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (var datum in data)
        {
            var autoData = autoDataAttribute.GetData(testMethod).ToArray()[0];

            for (var i = 0; i < datum.Length; i++)
            {
                autoData[i] = datum[i];
            }

            yield return autoData;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `ParameterizedClassDataAttribute` to abstract away `Activator.CreateInstance`, I managed just to use `CompositeDataAttribute` to have a `ClassAutoDataAttribute`:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Xunit.Sdk;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class ClassAutoDataAttribute : CompositeDataAttribute {
   public ClassAutoDataAttribute(Type @class, params object?[] args)
      : base(new ParameterizedClassDataAttribute(@class, args), new AutoMoqDataAttribute()) { }

   public ClassAutoDataAttribute(Type attributeType, Type @class, params object?[] args)
      : base((DataAttribute)Activator.CreateInstance(attributeType), new ParameterizedClassDataAttribute(@class, args), new AutoMoqDataAttribute()) { }

   /// <summary>
   /// Parameterized version of <see cref="ClassDataAttribute" />
   /// </summary>
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
   private sealed class ParameterizedClassDataAttribute : ClassDataAttribute {
      private readonly object?[] _args;
      public ParameterizedClassDataAttribute(Type @class, params object?[] args) : base(@class) => _args = args;

      /// <inheritdoc />
      public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod) {
         var data = (_args.Any() ? Activator.CreateInstance(Class, _args) : Activator.CreateInstance(Class)) as IEnumerable<object[]>;

         ThrowIfNull(data,
                     $"{Class.FullName} must implement IEnumerable<object[]> to be used as ClassData for the test method named '{testMethod.Name}' on {testMethod.DeclaringType!.FullName}");

         return data;
      }
   }
}
```

and it can be used like

```
ClassAutoDataAttribute(typeof(TestSpecificData))
```

and if `TestSpecificData` needs some args in its constructor:

```
ClassAutoDataAttribute(typeof(TestSpecificData), "arg1", "arg2",...)
```

and if another custom `AutoMoqDataAttribute` needs to be passed:

```
ClassAutoDataAttribute(typeof(CurrentAutoMoqDataAttribute), typeof(TestSpecificData), "arg1", "arg2",...)
```